# If kinetic energy increases 16 times, what's the percentage of change of De-Broghlie's wavelength?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, wavelength

seems easy but I'm not very convinced, if I made a  mistake please tell me

K.E1 = $\frac 12$m$v^2$  increases 16 times so

K.E2 = 8m$v^2$

so that means the momentum $mv$ must increase 16 times as the kinetic energy

$\lambda$1 = $\frac{h}{m_{}v}$
$\lambda$2 = $\frac{h}{16m_{}v}$

so that means $\lambda$2 = $\frac{1}{16}$$\lambda$1

so Δ$\lambda$ = $\frac{1}{16}$ - 1 = - $\frac{15}{16}$

so percentage of change of $\lambda$ = 93.75 % ?

Comment: What is the increase factor for velocity?

Comment: are you asking me or giving me a hint? all the information is in the title

Comment: That was a hint. If the energy changes 16x, the velocity changes ...x. The De Broglie wavelength is related to velocity as ..... - so the De Broglie wavelength changes by xxx which is ...%.

Comment: the velocity changes $(16)^2$ times?
and $\lambda$ = $\frac{h}{mv}$
so v = $\frac{h}{m\lambda}$

Comment: OK, try an easier one first. If I double the velocity, by what factor increases the KE?

Comment: if i double the velocity, K.E increases by 4 $v^2$

Comment: so if i double the velocity, K.E increases by 4 $v^2$
K.E1 = $\frac 12$ m$v^2$   so K.E2 = 2m$v^2$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the kinetic energy is $p^2/2m$, so by what do you multiply $p$?

Comment: I don't know these equations, the only ones we took in class is K.E = $\frac 12$ $mv^2$

and $\lambda$ = $\frac{h}{mv}$

Comment: @cazanova From $p=mv$ you can get what I stated.

Comment: oh P is the momentum, we call it PL which is linear momentum so I didn't pay attention, that means $v^2$ increases

Comment: can you answer it so that I could understand

Comment: @cazanova Since $p^2=m^2v^2=2Km$ has multiplied by $16$, $p$ has multiplied by $4$ while $\lambda$ has multiplied by $1/4$, i.e. has fallen by 75 %.